# "Saving" data in Python internally

Tags: python, r

I write code mainly in Python or R depending on the situation. However, one thing I REALLY like about R is that it saves your data into the IDE. So you can continue doing stuff on this data without the need to run all the code again each time. Is this even possible in Python, as elegant as R, or do I just have to save a file onto my HDD every time I compute some data that takes some time ?

Comment: Have you used Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend changing your IDE from what ever you are using to something like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and downloading the [Jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) extension or using [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/). It does precisely what you are asking for, saving variables during the session so you can modify them on the fly.

Compared with other IDEs, Visual Studio Code has the best support for jupyter that I have seen without using the notebook entirely based on my experiences using various IDEs.

Comment: -1, while Jupyter is a solid solution, it's totally unnecessary to recommend switching IDEs entirely (since editors and IDEs are overwhelmingly a very personal choice). Jupyter has the standalone Notebook environment for this kind of work.

Comment: @0xdd The Jupyter notebook environment does not save any data.

Comment: Seeing how I'm currently using it as we speak I beg to differ.

Comment: You mean the [`%store` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html)? That is actually an IPython feature. I totally forgot about it.

Comment: Another Great Solution! You should post it so others know about it also. Although OP indicated that they use IDEs and not command line

Comment: I am confused. What is your answer about, then? In what other way does Jupyter save data? I didn't find any hints in your links.

Comment: The reason why the OP placed "saved" in quotation marks is because he is not talking about saving data, but rather being able to run a command like list_1 = [1] and then use a line list_1.append(2) without needed to rerun the entire script but rather just the one line list_1. That is a feature that jupyter uses,  hence @Sonny comment. However since he mentioned he uses IDE I recommended one that I believe utilizes this feature that would be helpful, seeing how I ran into the same problem and found a solution.

Comment: That would be a weird question to ask since any interactive python environment does that and python is no different from R in that regard.